# Repertoire book on the Ruy Lopez exchange variation?

Tags: opening, books, ruy-lopez, 1.e4

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4.Bxc6
```

Is there a good opening repertoire book for White advocating the Ruy Lopez exchange variation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Larry Kaufman's *The Chess Advantage in Black and White* is a well-regarded (though old, by opening book standards) repertoire book that uses the Ruy Lopez exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I had also problems with finding good book about it. What is worth Chessbase has videos tutorial about it and I find it quite resourceful.

https://en.chessbase.com/post/robert-ris-fighting-the-ruy-lopez-exchange
https://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/spanish_exchange_variation